# Calcular distancia entre puntos cartesianos y agruparlos

Tags: algoritmos

Tengo puntos de una matriz que representan puntos en el plano cartesiano, por ejemplo:

```
(2,5)
(-5,8)
(3,6),
(9,2)
(-4,-4)
(8,-3)
(2,1)
```

Necesito crear grupos de cordenadas, por ejemplo grupos de 3 cordenadas, con las cordenadas que tengan menos distancia

Necesito creat un algoritmo que calcule distancias y haga grupos

Estaba pensando en usar la formula de distancia entre dos puntos:

```
d=sqrt(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

Pero así como lo tengo pensado calcularia la distancia de todos con todos y si la matriz es muy grande puede que tenga problemas de optimización

Por ejemplo entre (2,5) y (-5,8) la distancia es 7.6, entre (2,5) y (3,6) la distancia es 1.4, por lo que (2,5) y (3,6) tienen una distancia pequeña por lo que es posible que queden en el mismo grupo de cordenadas.

El problema es que deberia calcular la distancia de todos con todos?

O hay una mejor forma de calcular esto?

Comment: Amigo, este foro solo admite preguntas en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta y lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Efectivamente, el "clustering" clásico trabaja calculando las distancias de cada punto con cada punto. Y efectivamente hacer esto puede plantearte un serio problema de performance y de recursos. Para evitar esto hay algoritmos no tan "exactos" pero mucho más óptimos, por ej. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medias o https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_vecinos_m%C3%A1s_pr%C3%B3ximos